# Open Custom https link in My iOS App

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make my iOS app have the ability to open a specific https link, with a specific host:

https://my.site.com/segment/parameter

Now, I'm using this tutorial:

http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

I did everything as it says (as the "custom" url scheme I placed "https") but my app doesn't come up as an option when I press an https link.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure `https` is reserved, although I can't find any documentation on it. The way I see Apple and Spotify do it is having Javascript on the page in question check to see if the browser responds to that particular url scheme and if it does, redirecting the user to it (thereby having the OS open the app.)

Comment: @esqew - say it isn't so! is there someway at least for me to detect if my app is installed in js?

Comment: If your app is registering its own custom url scheme, there are some [hack-ish ways of checking](http://www.makebetterthings.com/javascript/how-to-check-if-url-scheme-is-supported-in-ios-safari-i-using-javascript/).